# Error while starting rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get the following error when I try to start the instant rails console
It was working fine previously and now I get this error:

```
C:\InstantRails\rails_apps\shovell>ruby script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.0.2)
C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- application (MissingSourceFile)
    from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `require'
    from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
    from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
    from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
    from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.0.2/lib/console_with_helpers.rb:19
    from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `gem_original_require'
    from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:27:in `require'
    from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
    from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `new_constants_in'
    from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in `require'
    from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:252:in `load_modules'
    from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:250:in `each'
    from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:250:in `load_modules'
    from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:21:in `setup'
    from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:54:in `start'
    from C:/InstantRails/ruby/bin/irb:13
```

Comment: I think you should do `rake gems:install` or `bundle install` before running server/console

Comment: @ RVG I am getting the following error when trying to install bundle   C:\InstantRails\rails_apps\shovell>bundle install
C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:379:in `report_activate_
error': Could not find RubyGem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:311:in `act
ivate'
        from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:65:in `acti
ve_gem_with_options'
        from C:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:50:in `gem'

        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/bundle:18

Comment: What is the output of `gem -v`?

Comment: @anand 1.0.1 gem version

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem with bundler.

All I did was Bundle install again and it is now working perfectly with me.